# GAS Spreadsheet how to check validity before applying

Tags: google-apps-script

Ok so this is the code in question. It gets the existing validations, clears them, inserts the data, and then re-establishes the validations.

```
  var validations = offSetRange.getDataValidations();
  offSetRange.clearDataValidations();
  offSetRange.setValues(v);
  console.log("Loff: %s", offSetRange.getA1Notation());
  offSetRange.setDataValidations(validations);
```

My problem is that if any of the validations are themselves invalid (they are trying to grab values from a local sheet that does not exist in some cases) it errors out and doesn't apply ANY of the validations.

This is the error:

> The data validation rule argument "='Data
> Validation'!$D$3:$D$4" is invalid.

Can anyone think of a way to cycle through the validations and determine if they are invalid first, and then replace any invalid validations with a generic validation that accepts all values? I don't want it to keep throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can loop through all the data validations one by one and use `try / catch` to replace the ones with errors:

```
  var generic = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied("=TRUE").build();
  var validations = offSetRange.getDataValidations();
  offSetRange.clearDataValidations();
  offSetRange.setValues(v);
  console.log("Loff: %s", offSetRange.getA1Notation());
  for (i = 0; i < validations.length; i++) {
    try {
      offSetRange.setDataValidation(validations[i]);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      offSetRange.setDataValidation(generic);
    }
  }
```

Comment: yep, that will work, although the range and the validations are actually a 2 dimensional array so it will have to be like [0][i] for both.  I just don't know if I want to take this much extra time putting the data back. I guess I will time it and see.